# Prevent submit button from duplicate in form

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm generating a form with all questions stored in the database. I don't understand how I can prevent the submit button from duplicate itself for every row (question)? I only want one submit button in the end of the form.

```
// generate all questions
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $body = $row['question_body'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];

    echo '  
        <tr>
            <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
                <td><input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="'.$question_id.'">'.$question_id, $body.'</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="3"></td>
                <input type="submit">
         </tr>
             </form>
                        <br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to move the submit button outside of the `while` loop. (As a side note, I prefer the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).)

```
<?
// Generate all questions
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) :
?>
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <table>
<?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
        $body = $row['question_body'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<? echo $question_id ?>"><? echo $question_body ?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="3"></td>
        </tr>
<?
    endwhile;
?>
        <tr>
            <input type="submit">
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the form start and end tags and the submit button outside the table (and the `while` loop).

Comment: i have tried it in various combinations but i don't get it to work. I dont get the form to submit at all when moving the form tags and submit button.